# Doorkeeper, OAuth, JWT with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, jwt, doorkeeper

I've already looked at dedicated Rails casts [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/353-oauth-with-doorkeeper?view=asciicast) and
[there](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1), as well some **Rails API** tutorials with **JWT** [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-json-api-with-rails-5-part-two) and [there](https://dev.mikamai.com/2015/03/02/oauth2-on-rails-the-client-application/) and [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/oauth2-and-so-can-you/). Unfortunately, most of them are too outdated (2011-2015).
Nevertheless, I'm a still a little bit lost what to choose between [oauth2](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2), [omniauth-oauth2](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-oauth2), [ruby-jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt)
and in which situation and how to glue all these bricks together.

To be short, I need to **authenticate Users** via an external corporate API, get **JWT token** and be able to decode it to extract User information
before let him enter the Rails application.
What should I do:

- create a custom strategy ?
- will this custom strategy work with the corporate authentication API
  if it does not use Doorkeeper ?

Some recent links would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-grants_assertion relevant to you?

Comment: @baxang Thank you for the link, I'll take a look for my future devs if needed. Actually, I'm using Ember as front-end solution backed by Rails API. Ember Simple Auth with implicit grant authentication way works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you want to use Open Id Connect mechanism, which Identity Provider (IdP) will return id_token (JWT format) to client. That mechanism is already implemented here: https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-openid_connect. Check it out!